# Plot a histogram with the x axis values based on the height of the column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

So say I have the following:

```
[1,5,1,1,6,3,3,4,5,5,5,2,5]

Counts: {1:3, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1, 5:5, 6:1}
```

Now, I wanted to print a plot like a histogram that is sorted on the x axis, as in:

A traditional histogram is:

```
        X  
        X
X       X  
X   X   X
X X X X X X
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

What I would want is:

```
        X  
        X
      X X  
    X X X
X X X X X 
2 4 3 1 5
```

My current plotting code is:

```
plt.clf()
plt.cla()
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.axvline(x=.85, color='r',linewidth=0.1)
plt.hist(correlation,2000,(0.0,1.0))
plt.xlabel(index[thecolumn]+' histogram')
plt.ylabel('X Data')

savefig(histogramsave,format='pdf')
```

Please help me out about how I can do this... I understand I posted a similar question before, but I believe I was unclear about it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Histogram is not the graph you are looking for. Use the bar chart.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5]
correlation = [(i, data.count(i)) for i in set(data)]
correlation.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

labels, values = zip(*correlation)

indexes = np.arange(len(correlation))
width = 1

plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar chart]

**EDIT:** For large set of data better use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of the list comprehension with `count`.

---

And here is the way to archive same result much faster (without neither bar chart nor hist):

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.random_integers(0, 10**4, 10**5)
correlation = Counter(data).items()
correlation.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
labels, values = zip(*correlation)
indexes = np.arange(len(correlation))

plt.plot(indexes, values)
plt.fill_between(indexes, values, 0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Inefficient to use `count` here for a large list since it iterates over the list for each unique element.

Comment: Thing is... I have a large list of about 9000 values of correlations, hence 0<x<1.0... Now, it seems that it doesn't work for it. Is it possibly because of the width that you have given? Could you explain that please?

Comment: As in, how would you expand this for such a large set of data?

Comment: I don't understand the question now. Do you need labels under each bar (like in your example)? If so how you want to show it with 9000 values? And without them all you need is just sort your correlations. Here is [expansion](https://gist.github.com/Igonato/5261480) for large (10^4) set of data (I removed width and labels)

Comment: And [here](https://gist.github.com/Igonato/5261567) is the way to archive same result much faster (without neither bar chart nor hist)